# Hive table not recognising partition

Tags: hive, bigdata, partitioning

My hive table is partitioned with column 'job_id'. When I dump the data in the hdfs location of the table, then it is creating a partition with name 'JOB_ID' and my hive table is not recognizing it.

I have tried msck repair table command but that didn't helped either.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "dump the data in the hdfs location"? Do you place some files in HDFS and then create external Hive table on it?

Comment: Partition folder name should be key=value, for example job_id=123456, not just job_id

Comment: @serge_k yes there are files in hdfs location and hive table point to that location.

Comment: @leftjoin It is like job_id=927

Comment: Please add table DDL with location and the result of hadoop fs -ls <table location>

Answer (score 0):

For external Hive tables you need to add new partition manually as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION (job_id='927') location 'hdfs://some_location/job_id=927'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the partition name should always be in lowercase letter.
Here is the link: 
https://medium.com/a-muggles-pensieve/hive-partition-column-name-camelcase-bad-idea-bc203d6e65da